# what is stream and stream wrapper in php

Tags: php, file, stream

For my understanding of streams in PHP, a stream is an interface that provides methods for
reading from and writing to a resource and this interface is implemented by different
types of stream wrappers (http,ftp,file etc) for providing specific functionality.
So when we say fopen() opens up stream, does it mean instantiation of a specific stream
wrapper object?
Please clarify me if i am wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all streams are implemented at that level, most built-ins are at C level, so no, as far as PHP is concerned not a `streamwrapper` object. That interface makes sure it *works* like a stream, not the other way around. (In essence: all streamwrappers can be accessed like a stream resource, but not all stream resources are provided by streamwrapper classes). You can however override for instance the `file:///` wrapper and other built-ins, great fun.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i am interested to know the meaning of "open up the stream" when we say something like fopen(ftp://path).So can you please provide me some explanation about it

Comment: A 'Stream' is no more then the a sequence of data. 'opening' that stream is gaining access to that data: in case of `ftp`, it's a `tcp` network connection, in case of (local) files, it's getting a pointer to a file descriptor, so, it varies based on what type you are actually using. It is hard to define 'opening' as anything other then _'all the things you have to do prior to either start reading or writing'_.